# How do I make the Visual Studio 2019 Output window "visible by default" on start again?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Some time ago, Visual Studio 2019 told me that the "Output" window caused a Visual Studio start-up delay of X seconds and offered me to hide the window on start.

I accepted that offer, and now, after some time, I discovered that having to re-pin the Output window once per Visual Studio session is super-annoying, and that I would like things back the way they were before.

I browsed through the Visual Studio options (specifically Environment/Startup and Environment/"Tabs and Windows"), but I did not find an option to undo that change. What did I miss?

---

I know that I could reset Visual Studio to default settings, but I want to avoid that, because then I'd lose all my custom settings. (No bounty will be awarded for suggesting this, unless the answer also proves that there is no other option.)

I also know that I could pin the output window and then "save" the layout as a custom layout. I don't want that, I want to modify the "default" layout loaded on start.

Answer (score 5):

*(Rubber-duck debugging at its best: 5 minutes after starting a bounty I find the solution myself. Go figure!)*

In the Visual Studio menu, go to `Help`/`Visual Studio Performance Manager`, which brings up this helpful dialog:

[image: screenshot]

Setting this option back to "Use default behavior" fixes the issue.